# Users creating a new page in ScrewTurn Wiki is not generating an approval message for the administrators

Tags: screwturn

My company adopted the screwturn wiki last year and we've noticed an issue when it comes to the creation of pages.

Whenever a member of the default user group creates a page, it does not generate an approval message that is sent to the administrator. I would like to activate this feature, but I am not really sure how.

I have activated the feature that sends an approval email every time that an edit is made to a page, but for some reason the creation of a page does not fall under that category.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What setting exactly are you using to "activate the feature that sends an approval email every time that an edit is made to a page"?  What version of Screwturn are you using?

Comment: I wasn't able to find a setting like that in my organization's set-up, either.